# What is preferred in the while loop of the RunAsync method in a Service: use IsCancellationRequested or throw exception

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Why is the sample RunAsync for new Service Fabric code structured like this

```
protected override async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  while(true)
  {
    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), cancellationToken);
  }
}
```

instead of this

```
protected override async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  while(cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
  {
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), cancellationToken);
  }
}
```

Wouldn't the version without the throw be preferred?
[The docs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-services-quick-start/) state that both implementations are correct: "The system will wait for your task to end (by successful completion, cancellation, or fault)".

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Service Fabric yet, but the expected semantics of setting a `CancellationToken` are to throw `OperationCanceledException` *if it was canceled*, and return *if the cancellation was too late*. It's possible they just have this code for consistency, or it's possible that Service Fabric will change how it does self-healing based on how `RunAsync` completes.

Comment: Yes, this is primarily why we changed the sample code to throw OperationCanceledException where a continuous loop in RunAsync is interrupted by Service Fabric by signaling the cancellation token, because the RunAsync loop is being canceled and this is the expected semantic. Other exception types are treated differently for self-healing by reporting a fault to the system.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer - both are fine. I'd use `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` because IMO it's the safer option. It's also more consistent - methods lower in the call chain can propagate cancellation via the exception.

Whenever an exception occurs in `RunAsync`, Service Fabric [reports](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.fabric.iservicepartition.reportfault.aspx) a transient fault (which means that the service is restarted without the instance/replica being recreated).

It gives special treatment for `OperationCanceledException` - if it was thrown by the cancellation token passed to the method, then the method is considered to have been successfully cancelled and no fault will be reported.

You can try this yourself by monitoring the `Microsoft-ServiceFabric-Services` ETW events.

Answer (score 0):

cancelToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

is equal to

if (token.IsCancellationRequested) 
    throw new OperationCanceledException(token);

Typically people use this as a control mechanism to ensure the current processing gets aborted without potentially running any extra code. Also, there is no need to check for cancellation when calling ThrowIfCancellationRequested()

Answer (score 0):

This is even simpler and works too:

```
protected override async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    while(true)
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

or

```
protected override async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    while(cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    }
}
```

I found out about this since my code was modeled after the sample code like this:

```
protected override async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)     
{
    var pipeline = ...
    pipeline.Start();

    while (true) {
        if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) {
            ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceMessage(Context, "Stopping pipeline");
            await pipeline.ShutdownAsync();
        }

        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

and the pipeline was never stopped. The solution was to not use the `cancellationToken` in the `Task.Delay` call.